# Error in showing progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I'am now trying to show loading progress bar while sending request to my server to register user data from facebook graph api.But I have an error." java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first".Could you take a look at this please.
Login.java

```
package fixmystreet.teamyolo.net.pyinpaypar;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.securepreferences.SecurePreferences;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

import fixmystreet.teamyolo.net.pyinpaypar.Api.LoginApi;
import fixmystreet.teamyolo.net.pyinpaypar.Api.MainService;
import fixmystreet.teamyolo.net.pyinpaypar.Utilties.FinalResult;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView greetTxt;
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    public String user_id;
    public String user_name;
    private SecurePreferences sharedPreferences;

    private String mail;
    ProgressBar myProgressBar;
    AlertDialog.Builder myDialogBuilder;


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        greetTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
        greetTxt.setTypeface(MainApplication.typefaceManager.getUnicode());

        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email"));

        myDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        myDialogBuilder.setTitle("loading");

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    JSONObject object,
                                    GraphResponse response) {

                                try {
                                    user_name = response.getJSONObject().get("name") + "";
                                    user_id = response.getJSONObject().get("id") + "";
                                    mail = response.getJSONObject().get("email") + "";
                                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Logging in.Please wait!",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    sharedPreferences = new SecurePreferences(getApplicationContext());
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                    editor.putString("id", user_id);
                                    editor.putString("name",user_name);
                                    editor.commit();

                                    MainApplication.securedUserId=user_id;
                                    MainApplication.securedUserName=user_name;


                                    Log.i("Before circular loading","Before circular loading");

                                    //for circular loading
                                    View ProgressView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.progressbar,null);
                                    myProgressBar=(ProgressBar)ProgressView.findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);

                                    myDialogBuilder.setView(myProgressBar);
                                    //myProgressBar.getParent().removeView();
                                    myDialogBuilder.create().show();


                                    register(user_id);

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                try {
                                    response.getJSONObject().get("id");
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.i("On Cancel", "On Cancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.i("ggwp", error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error in facebook login",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void setProfile() {
        getFacebookProfilePicture(user_id + "");
    }

    public void getFacebookProfilePicture(String userID) {

        try {
            String imageUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "/picture?type=large";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ReadRdaJSONFeedTask", e.getLocalizedMessage() == null ? "ERROR IS NULL" : "ERROR IS NOT NULL AND IT IS:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

    }

    public void register(String id) {


        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Logging in.Please wait!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String pic_link = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large";
        Call<HashMap<String, String>> register = LoginApi.createService(MainService.class).register(id, user_name, pic_link, mail);
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Logging in.Please wait!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        register.enqueue(new Callback<HashMap<String, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<HashMap<String, String>> call, Response<HashMap<String, String>> response) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Success Login!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("SUCCESS:", "MOTHER FUCKER");
                Log.i("Server Message:", response.message().toString());
                FinalResult.isLoggedIn = true;
                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<HashMap<String, String>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Facebook Login Fail!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

progressbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my log

```
05-25 20:52:43.712 2799-2855/fixmystreet.teamyolo.net.pyinpaypar E/chromium: [ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(313)] [.Parent-Compositor-0xe2b09a90]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
05-25 20:54:14.892 2799-2799/fixmystreet.teamyolo.net.pyinpaypar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: fixmystreet.teamyolo.net.pyinpaypar, PID: 2799
                                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3880)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3733)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3709)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.setupCustomContent(AlertController.java:610)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:449)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:214)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:240)
                                                                                       at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:373)
                                                                                       at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
                                                                                       at fixmystreet.teamyolo.net.pyinpaypar.Login$1$1.onCompleted(Login.java:112)
                                                                                       at com.facebook.GraphRequest$1.onCompleted(GraphRequest.java:304)
                                                                                       at com.facebook.GraphRequest$5.run(GraphRequest.java:1379)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Here is line 112 Login.java

```
 myDialogBuilder.create().show();
```

Comment: This usually means you're trying to add a view twice to a layout.

Comment: Would you mind telling me the place to fix the error please?Thanks

Comment: Post the whole logcat, it's important to see at what line you're getting that exception. Do highlight that line in the code.

Comment: I have added my error logs.Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me what line of code is at line 112 in Login.java? Logcat says the error occurs there. Edit the question with it, and then ping me in the comments so I get a notification, please.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. @Vucko

Comment: I think this answer I gave will fix it. Tell me how it goes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113047/discussion-between-vucko-and-min-htet-oo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to set the view as a whole layout, not a single element in it. Try to do it like this:

```
View ProgressView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.progressbar,null);
myDialogBuilder.setView(ProgressView);
myDialogBuilder.create().show();
```

Another piece of advice unrelated to this particular problem:

> Follow the naming conventions in Java; methods and variables are named with a lowercase letter at the start using **camelCase**; so in your case it would be `progressView`, and classes always start with an uppercase letter.